# Controlling the timing/delay of multiple CSS transitions

Tags: html, css, web

I'm working on a site where I have three divs, and when I hover over any one of them, I would like the div to extend in length and **then** I would like the text to change.

Currently, I've got it so that the div extends and the text changes at the same time. I can't figure out how to make the text change occur after the div finishes animating. I've tried adding this piece of code  `transition: .2s .2s;` to every class and id but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Here's a link to the page: http://colorsplash.co.uk/test.html

And here's the code:
HTML:

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box1">
        <div id="create-box" class="about-box"><span class="box-span">Create</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        <div id="produce-box" class="about-box"><span class="box-span">Produce</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
        <div id="collab-box" class="about-box"><span class="box-span">Collaborate</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.boxes{
   padding-top: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: Arial;
}
.about-box{
   height: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 150px;
   padding: 20px;
   color: white;
   background-color: black;
   margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
   -o-transition:.2s;
   -ms-transition:.2s;
   -moz-transition:.2s;
   -webkit-transition:.2s;
   transition:.2s;
}
.about-box:hover{
   width: 300px;
}
.box1,.box2,.box3{
   display: inline;
}
.box1:hover #create-box span{
   display: none;
}
.box1:hover #create-box:after{
   content: 'Create visual designs & interactive media';
}
.box2:hover #produce-box span{
   display: none;
}
.box2:hover #produce-box:after{
   content: 'Produce / Manufacture clothing pieces';
}
.box3:hover #collab-box span{
   display: none;
}
.box3:hover #collab-box:after{
   content: 'Collaborate on diverse creative projects';
}
```

Comment: I believe what you are looking for are keyframes

Comment: Why dont you use JQuery? Its much easier :)

Comment: If it really needs to be done with CSS, keyframe animations is the way to go. Let me know if you're new to keyframe animations. Ill help you out.

Comment: Yes, I have no idea what keyframes are. Do you know of a good resource where I can read about them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLWewb

```
.boxes{
   padding-top: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: Arial;
}
.about-box{
   height: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 150px;
   padding: 20px;
   color: white;
   background-color: black;
   margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
   -o-transition:.2s;
   -ms-transition:.2s;
   -moz-transition:.2s;
   -webkit-transition:.2s;
   transition:.2s;
}
.about-box:hover{
   width: 300px;
}
.box1,.box2,.box3{
   display: inline;
}

.about-box:after{
  white-space:nowrap;
   content:"";
  -o-transition:.2s;
   -ms-transition:.2s;
   -moz-transition:.2s;
   -webkit-transition:.2s;
   transition:.2s;
}

.box1:hover #create-box span{
   display: none;
}
.box1:hover #create-box:after{
   content: 'Create visual designs & interactive media';
}
.box2:hover #produce-box span{
   display: none;
}
.box2:hover #produce-box:after{
   content: 'Produce / Manufacture clothing pieces';
}
.box3:hover #collab-box span{
   display: none;
}
.box3:hover #collab-box:after{
   content: 'Collaborate on diverse creative projects';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how this effect can be done with the help of `transition`, Then here is the demo. I have used `transition-delay`. in order to delay the `transition` and used `visibility` to control the `pseudo-content` display. Just go through the snippet and you will understand the concept.

```css
.boxes {
      padding-top: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    
    .about-box {
      height: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 150px;
      padding: 20px;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
      -o-transition: .2s;
      -ms-transition: .2s;
      -moz-transition: .2s;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: all ease .2s;
    }
    .about-box:after {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .about-box:hover {
      width: 300px;
      transition: .5s ease-out; 
      transition-delay: 0s;
    }
    
    .box1,
    .box2,
    .box3 {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    .box1:hover #create-box span {
      display: none;
    }
    .box1 #create-box:after, .box2 #produce-box:after, .box3 #collab-box:after {
      content: '';
      visibility: hidden;
      transition-delay: .3s;
    } 
    .box1:hover #create-box:after {
      content: 'Create visual designs & interactive media';
      visibility: visible;
    }
    
    .box2:hover #produce-box span {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .box2:hover #produce-box:after {
      content: 'Produce / Manufacture clothing pieces';
      visibility: visible;
    }
    
    .box3:hover #collab-box span {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .box3:hover #collab-box:after {
      content: 'Collaborate on diverse creative projects';
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box1">
    <div id="create-box" class="about-box"><span class="box-span">Create</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <div id="produce-box" class="about-box"><span class="box-span">Produce</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    <div id="collab-box" class="about-box"><span class="box-span">Collaborate</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```